# Do I need to add Hibernate Search to my mid-level project?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I have a web project and I just want to learn that Do I need to use Hibernate Search? I did some research and everybody says Hibernate Search is decreasing query times but I don't get then why everybody doesn't use Hibernate Search. My project is some kind of student information system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate search is an hibernate plugin for full text indexation (using apache lucene) of some domain entities attributes. it will not decrease relational query execution time but will allow to query your model to search some occurrence of a given word (querying an index is indeed much more faster than querying about all your database content using 'like' restriction).

If you don't have full-text indexation problematic, you don't need to use hibernate-search.